# Generation of ABAP report in runtime possible?

Tags: dynamic, abap

Is there any Function module that can generate ABAP code.
For eg: FM takes tables name and join conditions as input and generate ABAP code corresponding to that.

Thanks

Comment: And how should the system determine what exactly the code should do? Read you mind?

Comment: There should be normal selection of data from the table depending upon the conditions specified .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Generic reports are possible.**

Your problem is, that You will have to draw a strict frame of what is
generic and what not, this means, some stuff MUST be that generic, that
it will deal with WHATEVER You want to do before ( mostly the selection ) ,
during ( mostly manipulation  ---> I would offer a badi for that ), and output.
This means, that there is at least the output-step, which can be valid for ALL
data resulting from the steps before.
Consider a generic ALV-table_output, there are a lot of examples in the repo.
If You want to be the stuff printed out simple as  list, this might include
more work, like, how big is the structure,  when Dou You wrap a line, and so on, consider using a flag which allows to toggle the type of output  .

**2. Generic reports are a transportable object.**

This refers to point one. Define clear stages and limits. What does the report do, and what is it not able to do. Because, even if it is in customer's namespace, each modification still will be put into transport-layers. Therefore a strict definition of features/limits is necessary so that the amount of  transports due to "oh, but we also need that"-statements will not become infinite.

**2. Generic reports are strict.**

What does that mean ? You might want to parse the passed data  ( table names, join-binding, selection-parameter-values ) and throw exceptions, if not properly set. Much work. You should offer a badi for that. If You do not do this, expect a dump. let it dump. In the end the user of Your report-api should know ( by documentation perhaps) how to call it. If not, a dynamic SQL-dump will be the result.

**3. Generic reports might benefit from badis/exits.**

This is self explanaining, I think. Especially generic/dynamic selection/modification/displaying of data should be extendable in terms of
custom-modifications. When You inspect, what a f4-search-help exit works like, You will understand, what I mean.

**4. Generic coding is hard to debug, mostly a blackbox.**
Self explaining, in the code-section below I can mark some of those sections.

**5. Generic coding has some best prectice examples in the repo.**

Do not reinvent the wheel. Check, how the se16n works by debugging it, 
check how se11 works by debugging it. Check, what the SQL-Query-builder
looks like in the debugger. You will get the idea very soon, 
and the copy-paste should be the most simple part of Your work.

**6. That are the basic parts of what You might use.**

Where clause determination and setting the params.

```
 data lt_range     type rsds_trange.
 data ls_range_f   type rsds_frange.
 data lt_where     type rsds_twhere.
 data ls_where     like line of lt_where.


ls_range_f =  value #( sign   = _sign
                       option = _option
                       low    = _low
                       high   = _high ). 


.
.
.

append ls_frange to lt_range.
.
.
.

 call function 'FREE_SELECTIONS_RANGE_2_WHERE'
  exporting
    field_ranges  = lt_range
  importing
    where_clauses = lt_where.
```

You have the parameter, let us create the select-result-table.

```
data(lt_key) = value abap_keydescr_tab( for line in _joinfields)
                                                  ( name = fieldname ) ).
data(lo_structdescr) = cast cl_abap_structdescr(    cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_name( _struct_name ) ).
data(lo_tabledescr)  = cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( line_type  = lo_structdescr                                                       p_key        = lt_key ).

create data ro_data type handle lo_tabledescr.
```

.
.
.

```
 select  (sel_st)
    from    (sel_bind)
    into    corresponding fields of table t_data
    where   (dyn_where).
```

Then assign the seelct-table-result-reference  to the generic table of this select.

Do You need more hints ?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This is something that I wanted. I have also created a custom report for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using SAPQuery. SAP documentation here: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/d2/cb3efb455611d189710000e8322d00/content.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such possibility exists, but not by means of function modules. `INSERT REPORT` [statement](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapinsert_report.htm) allows generating report by populating its code from internal text table:

```
INSERT REPORT prog FROM itab 
          [MAXIMUM WIDTH INTO wid] 
          { [KEEPING DIRECTORY ENTRY] 
          | { [PROGRAM TYPE pt] 
              [FIXED-POINT ARITHMETIC fp] 
              [UNICODE ENABLING uc] } 
          | [DIRECTORY ENTRY dir] }.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is to create a ABAP report using the conditions. I want a FM in which I ma passing tables name and fields and join conditions. Using this information it will generate a ABAP report and this report will give the data selected from the tables mentioned. If not  a standard FM , is there any custom code for thsi.

Comment: @AKS : Can you re-check your requirements ? Prima facie it doesn't seem complete  to me. Are you saying you want to dynamically generate an ABAP Report ( This has a specific meaning in ABAP as a repository object ) , build the dynamic sql based on your inputs and then ...what ? What do you mean by 'give the data selected' ? Not only is there a lot of security risk here but I fail to see the utility here unless some other details are added.

Comment: @AKS, why do you need dynamic report generation? As report is a repository object, it should be created only once and then reused. So I see little sense in such dynamic generation, provided even such capability exists.

Comment: If you need to do some selection with different parameters each time, then create usual parametrized report (with selection screen) or use [SAP Query](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27049)

Comment: Yes I want to dynamically generate an ABAP report in SE38. Lets say, there is a FM XYZ. As an input parameter I am passing tables name, fields to be selected from the tables and join conditions on the tables and also the name of the report that will be generated in SE38. When I will execute this FM , it will generate a ABAP program in SE38. And this ABAP program( having complete code of declaration of tables and SQL query ) will fetch record from the tables that I specified in the FM.

Comment: @AKS : That still doesn't answer "why". What is the point of dynamically creating such reports with no parameters ? Does your input FM have only join conditions or even have join values ? What is the need to have separate reports created ? What is the criteria you use to generate a unique report from the input request ? How will take care of the security aspect here that people don't input tables and join conditions that they are not supposed to access ?

What is it you are trying to achieve by this approach ?

Comment: @AKS, updated the answer, but still have no idea why you need this:)

Comment: Actually I think you need a dynamic variant of the select statement. You can construct dynamic from clause also for Joins. There is an example in the [ABAP Online documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/index.htm) within the Select - Source section.